# tsq - take the highest int in duplicate row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following rows in a table

```
name, tagid
-------
test1,1
test1,100
test2,2
test2,200
test3,3
test3,300
```

There are duplicates in the name.
Is there a way to select unique names by taking the highest tagid of each group?

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you search for solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name,max(tagid) as highest_tagid
from tbl
group by name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY tagid DESC) AS rn
   FROM table_1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```